# How can one use reinforcement learning for optimal parameter determination to minimize output in dynamical systems?

Tags: reinforcement-learning

Assume that we have a discrete dynamical system of the form

$x(k+1)=f(x(k), u(k), p)$

$y(k)=g(x(k))$

where $u$ is the input, $y$ output, $x$ internal state of the system and $p$ is an unknown fixed parameter.

How can we use a reinforcement learning approach to find optimal
value of $p$ so that $y$ is minimized on average for a given set of inputs?

Comment: Why do you need RL to estimate this? It doesn’t seem like a sequential decision making process

Comment: I know but I want to solve it as an RL problem. I am sure that there are multiple ways to model it as an RL problem.

Comment: My advice would be to avoid overcomplicating things. RL is very very data intensive, you could solve this with supervised learning in a much more efficient manner.

Comment: I changed the problem statement to better express my objective. I think RL is suited better.